# How can I assign content to specific signed in user within Flamelink and React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, flamelink-cms

I am using Firebase with React Native and just started with Flamelink as my CMS.

Before using Flamelink, I was able to obtain specific content from a logged-in user via firebase realtime database because the schema was:

```
**fruits**
mwaKRypUrNb8rJdsj9YUxw0sA892
-M055RlZ7HBzgRD9LS1d
-M055Why2psB2kqE4mYO
-M05W3LK8C1kgFsPNRqa
-M05W47cbhJ2VA_Y2nnT
-M05W5Wu9Pp6TZJJPc8t
-M05W6Xc_iP1upbyENpj
-M05W7JnVt3t3DsjNaRT
-M05W8OuZph-1gDDY9UX
-M05W9Fws0_hsNCAyKDt
**users**
-zFWGnGhEmbfhjAJsUT99ZbkJBZ33
```

As you can see, the fruits schema had user-specific content.

With Flamelink the schema looks like this:

```
**flamelink**
--environments
----production
------content
--------**fruitEntryForm**
----------en-US
------------1582070066847
------------1582074440836
------------1582080914427

**schemas**
**media**
**permissions**
**settings**
**users**
--zFWGnGhEmbfhjAJsUT99ZbkJBZ33
```

My react native code is below:

```
const user = navigation.getParam("user");
     const currentUserData = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("flamelink/users")
      .child(user.uid)
      .once("value");

const fruits = await app.content.get("content");
```

How can I modify Flamelink so that I can manage content based on which user is signed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, your Fruits collection can be linked to multiple users and the main problem is that the Firebase Realtime Database does not allow querying for a value inside an array. Cloud Firestore is a bit better in that regard.

What I would suggest you do to simplify your queries is to turn the relationship on its head. I would have the Fruits collection that you currently have without a relationship to any users. Then I would create a "Users Fruit" collection that has a field for the user's UID with a relational select field that maps to multiple entries in your Fruits collection.

From your React Native app, you can then use our SDK to query the "Users Fruit" collection and expand the related Fruits.

Depending on the version of the SDK you are using, the syntax might differ a bit, but for the latest SDK it will look like this:

```js
const userFruit = await app.content.get({
  schemaKey: 'usersFruit', // assuming schema key is this
  orderByChild: "user", // assuming your field is called 'user'
  equalTo: "mwaKRypUrNb8rJdsj9YUxw0sA892", // assuming this is your user's uid
  populate: ['fruits'] // assuming you called the select relational field 'fruits'
})
```

Comment: Awesome. Got it to work. Thank you for your advice.